# Контроль отключения драйвера камеры при помощи vfw.h (avicap32)

Tags: c++, winapi, видео

В классе камеры есть функция

```
bool Camera::CaptureFrame(bool rotate){
    Rotated = rotate;
    return capGrabFrame(CaptureWindow);
}
```

На api-вызов `capGrabFrame` подвязан соответствующий callback. Проблема заключается в том, что если камеру USB просто выдернуть из порта, приложение зависает и крашится, так как, насколько я понимаю, из списка устройств теряется драйвер камеры, который забинден на `CaptureWindow`. А нужно, чтобы приложение не крашилось, а фиксировало ошибку и сообщало о ней пользователю.

**Вопрос заключается в том, как правильно отлавливать ошибки обращения к драйверу?** Есть в vfw.h `LRESULT CALLBACK capErrorCallback(HWND hWnd, int nID, LPCTSTR lpsz);`, но я что-то не пойму какой id ошибки оно требует на вход, если я ещё не получил никакой ошибки, и поможет ли данный коллбек решить проблему?

Comment: Если крашится, значит и ловить ошибку надо через `try/catch` или  `__try/__except`. Считайте, что краш в API маловероятен, ищите его сначала у себя.

Comment: @mega, да в потоке не особо-то try / catch работает. Крашится только при исчезании драйвера из списка устройств, когда usb-камера отключается физически. И из-за это я не могу считать, что тут маловероятен краш api, так как только вызов этой функции крашит приложение. тестами всё покрыто.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимально воспроизводимый пример. Возможно, Вы даже решите при этом свою проблему. В такой случае - оформляйте ответом.